# Facebook share javascript is not working with norwegian text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, facebook, razor

I have a javascript that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#share_button@(number)').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   FB.ui(
{
    method: 'feed',
    name: '@(item.Title)',
    link: ' http://www.newsifi.com',
    picture: 'http:/url/img/bla.png',
    caption: 'demo',
    description: '@(item.Description)',
    message: ''
});
                    });
                });
</script>
```

`@(item.Description)` displays:

> En person er hardt skadet etter en frontkollisjon mellom en
>   campingbil og en annen bil på E6 sør for Otta i Gudbrandsdalen.

When I check in chrome this is the error:

[image: Error]

So basicly the share function is not working anymore.

How can I fix this?

I have tried to change  `@(item.Description)` to `@Server.UrlEncode(item.Description)` it works but it displays very weird in the facebook share popup.

This is how it looks like:

```
description: 'En+person+er+hardt+skadet+etter+en+frontkollisjon+mellom+en+campingbil+og+en+annen+bil+p%c3%a5+E6+s%c3%b8r+for+Otta+i+Gudbrandsdalen.%0a',
```

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Note:

I checked how this javascript works with swedish text and it seems to work even if it looks like this SS.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can clearly see from the generated source code, you have a newline inside your Javascript string literal.

That isn't valid Javascript.

You need to *Javascript-encode* the string to escape characters like newlines that cannot appear in string literals.
Call `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode()`.

`UrlEncode()` is wrong because this isn't a URL.

Comment: hmm how can I use it in my javascript?

Comment: @Rohander: Look at your source code.  The problem is that the Razor code is writing illegal Javascript.  What don't you understand?

Comment: I dont understand how I can use the JavascriptStringEncode() around my razor @(item.description).